# How can I retain the archive.php loop filters when triggering with AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, packery

I've been working off this [Getting Loopy](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-loopy-ajax-powered-loops-with-jquery-and-wordpress--wp-23232) tutorial to append posts onto my [Packery.js](http://packery.metafizzy.co/)
layout and it works splendid on my home page, but whenever I try to use it for my archive (archive.php) pages it continues to load all posts rather than the posts specific to that category (or search query, etc). How can I retain the filtering WordPress's archive.php loop seems to inherently have while triggering it with AJAX?

Currently, I have a standard `<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>` as the main loop on the archive.php page, which is correctly calling the first twelve category posts. I've then been trying to use a second loop to append additional posts. As I said before, this calls all posts (not just the category). My current attempt has been to identify the category in the second loop, but I seem to be getting that wrong. Relevant current code is below (unaltered code is on the tutorial link above). Any ideas? Thanks!

The AJAX trigger script in the footer:

```
var pager = 1;
var archive_load_posts = function(){  
    $.ajax({  
        type       : "GET",  
        data       : {pageNumber: pager},  
        dataType   : "html",  
        url        : "http://tay.is/designing/belmontvision/wp-content/themes/yamidoo/archive-more-loop.php",  
        beforeSend : function(){},  
        success    : function(data){  
            var $data = $(data);  
            $container.append( $data ) .packery( 'appended', $data );
            heightcalc();
            $container.packery();
        }
    });
};

$('.archive-load-more').click( function() {
    archive_load_posts();
    pager++;
});
```

The base of the archive-more-loop.php:

```
<?php   require_once('../../../wp-load.php');   
        $page = (isset($_GET['pageNumber'])) ? $_GET['pageNumber'] : 0;
        $category = get_queried_object_id();

        query_posts(array(  
            'paged' => $page,
            'cat' => $category
        ));  

        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The AJAX request represents a ***new*** request to the server. It does not execute "inside" the original page. Things like `get_queried_object()` won't work, or at best will return something different than the originating page.

You will have to explicitly pass any information to the AJAX handler script-- since you are using `GET` you will need to append query variables to this line, `"http://tay.is/designing/belmontvision/wp-content/themes/yamidoo/archive-more-loop.php"`, so that it looks more like this `"http://tay.is/designing/belmontvision/wp-content/themes/yamidoo/archive-more-loop.php?category=123"` That means that your `archive_load_posts` script needs to find the category, or any other information, and pass it along.

If you are printing this directly to the footer, and it looks like you might be, then you can do something like this ***might*** work:

```
$category = get_queried_object_id(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var archive_load_posts = function(){  
        $.ajax({  
            type       : "GET",  
            data       : {pageNumber: pager},  
            dataType   : "html",  
            url        : "http://tay.is/designing/belmontvision/wp-content/themes/yamidoo/archive-more-loop.php?category=<?php echo $category ?>",  
            beforeSend : function(){},  
            success    : function(data){  
                var $data = $(data);  
                $container.append( $data ) .packery( 'appended', $data );
                heightcalc();
                $container.packery();
            }
        });

};
</script><?php
```

Problems:

1. WordPress loads jQuery in ["noConflict"](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode. The `$` alias
   won't work though code not posted might correct that.
2. You are completely ignoring the [WordPress AJAX API](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) forcing
   potentially unreliable hacks like
   `require_once('../../../wp-load.php');`. The way to properly do this
   would be to [register](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) and [enqueue](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) your script and use
   [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to write variables to the page. To get an idea  of what that looks like, see [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/108145/21376)(mine) on wordpress.stackexchange.com